# One verb, 5 senses

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a SINGLE verb/phrasal verb that can describe all 5 senses at once (feel, smell, taste, sound & sight), or at least 2 of them (I need smell & sound)?
An example: He (the verb I'm looking for) the delicious smell of dinner & the cheerful conversation of his family members.

Comment: **To experience**? Can you provide the sentence where you would use this word so that we know what you’re looking for?

Comment: Smell and sound are not related... Can you elaborate on what you mean? Please also provide an example sentence.

Comment: Uh, how about "sense" -- "He sensed the presence of another person."

Comment: No, there isn't, but there are a number of metaphors (suggested here and there) that can be pressed into use to refer to unspecified sensation.

Comment: He was aware of ...

Answer (score 2):

*Perceive* works:

> *He perceived the delicious smell of dinner and the cheerful conversation of his family members.*

---

> **perceive** *verb* **2 :** to become aware of through the senses
>  <sub>Source:
>   [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceive)</sub>

---

Other verbs that could work, depending on the context:

> *sensed*, *experienced*, *noticed*, *noted*, *identified*, *recognized*, *appreciated* . . .

As a matter of style, I would instead try a prepositional phrase:

> *He was immersed in the delicious aroma of dinner and the cheerful conversation of his family members.*

Also, depending on context:

> *surrounded by* (passive), *enveloped in*, *overwhelmed by* (passive), *lost in* . . .

Answer (score 1):

*Take in*

> to receive into the mind : perceive

[[source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take-in)]

Also: *sense* or *perceive*, but these give a more detached tone than you're probably looking for in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I like [**detect**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detect):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : to discover or determine the existence, presence, or fact of
>   // *detect* alcohol in the blood
>   // Do I *detect* a note of sarcasm in your voice?

So:

> He *detected* the delicious smell of dinner and the cheerful conversation of his family members.

[**Noticed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notice) is an alternative. Both sound more casual than to me than similar words. In such a sentence (unless it's a robot doing the sensing), I would prefer a less clinical word.

And for something other than a single word, you could use *became aware of*.

Answer (score 1):

OP sentence: He *relished* the delicious smell of dinner & the cheerful conversation of his family members.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/relish

> ...The verb relish means to enjoy something immensely. You may relish
>   eating the relish on your hotdog, or you may relish taking an
>   afternoon nap.
>
> relish
>   1. nv vigorous and enthusiastic enjoyment

**Anything But Civil**
By Anna Loan-Wilsey

> "I'm intrigued by your new book and would relish some stimulating
>   conversation.” Sir Arthur's eyes lit up. I could see why they had
>   continued their friendship."